# Reactjs-how change the value of the data using textbox which is fethched from server

Tags: reactjs

```
<ul>{this.state.data1.map(person =><li>
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<input type="text" name="fname" value={person.FirstName}  onChange={this.onChange} className="box1" placeholder="Enter your first name" required />
   </form>
</li>)}
</ul>
```

Here i was trying to display the data in textbox which can be editable
the data is fetched from server which is working
By using the above code,i can able to display the data in the textbox which is fetched 
But i cant edit that data.
so please help me how to edit the data which was i displayed

Comment: The value of your input is taken from `person`: `value={person.FirstName}`. I guess you are trying to update the value using `onChange` method, can you post your onChange method?

Comment: onChange = (e) => {
        const state = this.state
        state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState(state);
      }

Comment: this is my onchange code

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `onChange` directly, Instead, you can create your own method and pass it to onChange:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let state = Object.assign({}, this.state); // You should create a brand new Object
    state[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
}
```

And then pass it to your input:

```
<input onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

For a deeper explanation, check [this doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: i have used this onchange method, even though its not allowed to edit the data in textbox..

Comment: Hi Hari, just checking if you are able to resolve this issue or not.